# Force Visual Studio 2010 to use gacutil.exe from older versions (Post Build event)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, gac, post-build-event, gacutil

I'm developing a simple installer using `WiX` on which I'm trying to install a .dll and a publisher policy on GAC.

I successfully add the .dll on GAC using the installer. But I want to use PostBuild events from Visual Studio to execute msbuild commands. The order of the things I need to do is:

1. Create the `publisher policy` on a Post build event of Visual Studio.
2. Execute the command `al /link:the.config /out:the.policy.dll /keyfile:thekey.snk /platform:x86`
3. Publish the policy using a specific GACUTIL.

If I'm correct, if I execute `gacutil -i Policy.1.0.TestLibrary.dll`, Visual Studio will install this policy on the new GAC<sup>1</sup>, and I want to use the older one<sup>2</sup>.

How can I tell Visual Studio to use a specific gacutil on a Post Build event?

I tried this for PostBuild events:

```
al /link:"$(SolutionDir)"TestLibrary.dll.config /out:"$(SolutionDir)"Policy.1.0.TestLibrary.dll /keyfile:"$(SolutionDir)"sgKey.snk /platform:x86
```

But get `The command "...." exited with code 9009.`

Also, if I publish Library.v1.0.dll on the old GAC, and then I install Library.v2.0.dll on the new GAC, if I create a publisher policy from v1.0 to v2.0, will they find each other?

[1]: GAC used for .Net Framework 4.0 and above.
 [2]: GAC used for .Net Framework 3.5 and below.

Comment: Just specify the full path of the gacutil.exe version you want to use.  Like C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\gacutil.exe.  Running gacutil.exe on your dev machine is a Very Bad Idea btw.  Also quite useless to test anything, the customer's machine won't have gacutil.exe available.

Comment: I agree. I ended up building my own policy with the desired gacutil and inserting policy and library manually on WiX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved. There was an inconsistency on the policy, and that's why it wasn't working...